# Function mapping Delphi DLL with Java (JNA)

Tags: java, delphi, dll, jna

I'm having problems when trying to use two functions of a DLL in Delphi with the JNA Java. In Test Software (Delphi, provided with DLL by ), I have this functions (working perfectly in test software):

```
function abrir_conexao (const modelo : **byte**; const host : **pansichar**; const porta : **word**; const senha : **pansichar**) : integer; stdcall external 'comunicacao.dll';

function enviar_comando (const comando : **byte**; var tamanho : **byte**; var dados : **pbyte**) : integer; stdcall external 'comunicacao.dll';
```

I'm trying to implement these functions in Java (JNA). I'm getting usually load the dll , however , I believe that the problem lies in the use of correct primitive variables:

```
public int abrir_conexao (**byte** modelo, **String** host, **short** porta, **String** senha);

public int enviar_comando(**byte** comando, **byte** tamanho, **byte[]** dados);
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help ?

Comment: "It is not working" is never enough. Please describe how this fails.

Comment: JNA is for Java code to call into native code. JNI is for native code to call into Java code. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Remy No. Both JNI and JNA are for calling native code from Java. JNI supports the native code calling back into Java as well.

Comment: Your edit still offers nothing more than "it's not working". Please read the site help area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following native functions:

```
function abrir_conexao (const modelo : byte; const host : pansichar; const porta : word; const senha : pansichar) : integer; stdcall external 'comunicacao.dll';

function enviar_comando (const comando : byte; var tamanho : byte; var dados : pbyte) : integer; stdcall external 'comunicacao.dll';
```

JNA mapping:

```
public interface MyLibrary extends StdCallLibrary {
    MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary)Native.loadLibrary('comunicacao', MyLibrary.class);
    int abrir_conexo(byte modelo, String host, short port, String senha);
    int enviar_comando(byte comando, byte tamanho, byte[] dados);
}
```

Comment: technomage ... I having problem with pbyte (Delphi) and byte[] (Java) ... Not working ... The command "enviar_comando" always return 0 (fail) where 1 (is success). Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Are you certain your `byte[]` is big enough?  Usually you'd have an additional argument indicating how big the buffer is you're passing.